# Fixed width center, dynamic left and right background-image columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I've found a few ways to kinda do what I'm trying, but I'm not sure what exactly is the best or preferred way to do this... basically I want to have a 1000px fixed width #main div, then on the left and right side I want to have two separate images that can fill up more width if the resolution is big enough, but if not the images don't count towards the document width. Hope that makes sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: Kind of hard to understand what you want to do. If you attempt to do it and post some code it will provide us better understanding

Comment: if the resolution is not big enough, do you want to hide those 2 images on the sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a background image (say bg.jpg) 1400px width. put the left and right images onto this bg.jpg.

left image goes to the left most, right image goes to the right most of bg.jpg. at the end you will only have 1 image, that is bg.jpg.

if you main wrapper is center aligned, then you can add the css to body, so the background image is center align as well. but the main wrapper wont covered the left right images.

```
body{
background-image: url("bg.jpg") center 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This works great, the only problem is that I have to create a large 1400x500 image with 1000px blank in the center, as opposed to two separate 200x500 images... so just seems like more bandwidth this way. But the CSS is really clean and easy and it behaves just like I want, so this is the best solution yet!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set those two images as background images: (very simple)

```
background-image: url("background_one.png"), url("background_two.png");
background-position: left top, right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: I thought this would be the easiest solution, however I don't want the image to be positioned in the top left or top right. I do want it top positioned, but I want the left and right align to be right next to the #main div, so they can move dynamically as the page is resizes.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your two side images are 200px wide each, so you would only want to show them if the viewport is wider than 1400px.

You can do that with CSS media queries.

```
.side-img {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
    .side-img {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that some old browsers (IE7, 8) don't understand media queries, so the side images will never display in those browsers.

If that's an issue then you might prefer a JavaScript based solution, something along the lines of this jQuery function:

```
$(window).bind('resize',function(e){
    calcWidth(); // Called whenever window is resized.
});

function calcWidth(){    
    var sideImgs = $('.side-img');
    var winW = $(window).width();
    if (winW > 1400){
        sideImgs.css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        sideImgs.css('display', 'none');
    }
}

calcWidth();​ // Run this on page load.
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I can leave out the js as I don't care if it doesn't display in old browsers. The only problem I have with this is that I still want the image to display if, say, the window is 1200 width, it would still show 100px of both the left and the right, just cut off halfway. I thot using a background image on a #wrapper div of #main, but I can't figure out how to position the left/right of the background image to dynamically reposition and always be right up next to the #main div.